# How do I compress this Oracle resultset into values according to row priority, ignoring nulls?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, analytic-functions

I'll simplify the problem as much as possible:

I have an oracle table:

```
row_priority, col1, col2, col3
0, .1, 100, {null}
12, {null}, {null}, 3
24, .2, {null}, {null}
```

Desired result:

```
col1, col2, col3
.2, 100, 3
```

So according to the priority of the row, it overrides previous row values, if given.

I'm attempting to work out a solution using analytical functions over the table, but it just isn't behaving...

I try:

```
select last_value(col1 ignore nulls) over () col1,
       last_value(col2 ignore nulls) over () col2,
       last_value(col3 ignore nulls) over () col3
from (select * from THE_TABLE order by row_priority)
where rownum = 1
```

or the inverse:

```
select first_value(col1 ignore nulls) over () col1,
       first_value(col2 ignore nulls) over () col2,
       first_value(col3 ignore nulls) over () col3
from (select * from THE_TABLE order by row_priority desc)
where rownum = 1
```

And neither seem to ignore nulls.  Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put rownum = 1 OUTSIDE the analytical query

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   select          last_value(col1 ignore nulls) over () col1,
                            last_value(col2 ignore nulls) over () col2,
                            last_value(col3 ignore nulls) over () col3
            from (select * from THE_TABLE ORDER BY ROW_PRIORITY)
        )
WHERE   ROWNUM = 1
```

which results in (using your values above):

```
COL1   COL2    COL3
------ ------- ----
0.2    100     3
```

Comment: See an additional discussion I started regarding the nature of ordering with analytics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262278/oracle-analytics-partitions-and-ordering-of-sql-queries.  While your edits works in this case, you should still order within the partition clause.

Comment: I disagree about ordering in the partition clause, though I 'd like to see the plan.  My results are already ordered, and I'm taking advantage of documented functionality.  I wouldn't want it to reorder it 3 times.

Answer (score -1):

The COALESCE function may be of help to you here.  Perhaps like ...

```
select first_value(coalesce(col1,0) ignore nulls) over () col1,
       first_value(coalesce(col2,0) ignore nulls) over () col2,
       first_value(coalesce(col3,0) ignore nulls) over () col3
from THE_TABLE
```

Comment: wouldn't that be replacing nulls with 0's?  Not what I'm looking for at all!

Comment: Settle down, Beavis.  I wrote that it MAY be of help to you... just an idea.  You make a fine point about the zeros.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative:

```
SELECT
  MAX(col1) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY row_priority),
  MAX(col2) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY row_priority),
  MAX(col3) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY row_priority)
FROM the_table
```

The performance of this may be different from the analytic version; whether it is better or worse depends on your data and environment.